# How to do a cross tab where the number of columns varies? (ADO SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado

I'm trying to write a query that has a variable number of columns depending on the data but I've never done this kind of thing.

We're running ADO and hope to have a single query (possibly with subqueries) but no other coding or GO statements, stored procedures, etc.

We're planning to use the results of this query in an editable grid.

Below is a sample of our data.  We have a list of employees and a list of Projects. Note that this isn't a "summed" cross tab. There's only one source number per cell.

We want the query results to have one column for each project. The cells in this column would contain the hours for that employee on that project.

If we add a project, we want another column to appear in the query results.

Edit: Since we're writing the query in code and the submitting it, we can generate as the query dynamically. We need not dynamically generate the code. For example, in our data below, we'll be able to read (in our native language) the Project table and know we have 3 projects and what their names are. We can use them in a Pivot I'm seeing from reading up, but just not sure how...

[image: Crosstab source and results]

Comment: Please, post your tries and if possible, create a mockup at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [Rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode) to make easy support you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ded1/6

```
declare @pivotquery as nvarchar(max)
declare @columnname as nvarchar(max)
select @columnname= isnull(@columnname + ',','') 
      + quotename(name)
from (select name from project) as t2
set @pivotquery = 
     N'with t1 as (
         select ph.employee, e.name as empname, p.name, ph.hours
         from project_hours ph
         inner join project p
         on p.id = ph.project
         inner join employees e
         on e.id = ph.employee
       )
       select *
       from t1
       pivot(sum(hours) for name in (' + @columnname + ')) as pivot_table'
exec sp_executesql @pivotquery
```

with significant help and further explanation here: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

EDIT: As I read your question again, I notice that you're building the query in code, in which case you probably don't need the utility above, but a simple pivot where you build the `for name in` clause in your program, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ded1/12

```
with t1 as (
  select ph.employee, e.name as empname, p.name, ph.hours
  from project_hours ph
  inner join project p
  on p.id = ph.project
  inner join employees e
  on e.id = ph.employee
)
select *
from t1
pivot(sum(hours)
      for name in ([First Floor], [Basement], [Parking Lot A]))
      as hours_summary
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, here is a generalizable ANSI-syntax SQL query using two nested derived table subqueries.

This query should be compliant on most RDMS (SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2) as it uses no CTE Window functions (`WITH`) or database-specific functions like SQL Server's `Pivot()`:

```
SELECT [Key], [Employee Name], [Age],
       Max(FF) As [First Floor],
       Max(BSMT) As [Basement],
       Max(PRKLotA) As [Parking Lot A]    
FROM (
   SELECT dT.Key,
          dT.[Employee Name],
          dT.[Age],
          CASE WHEN dT.Project = 'First Floor' THEN dT.Hours END As FF,
          CASE WHEN dT.Project = 'Basement' THEN dT.Hours END As BSMT,
          CASE WHEN dT.Project = 'Parking Lot A' THEN dT.Hours END As PRKLotA
   FROM (
          SELECT [Employees].Key, 
                 [Employees.[Employee Name], 
                 Employees.Age, Projects.Project, 
                 [Project Hours].Hours
          FROM [Project Hours] 
          INNER JOIN Employees ON [Project Hours].[Employees FK] = Employees.Key 
          INNER JOIN Projects ON [Project Hours].[Projects FK] = Projects.Key
   ) AS dT
) As dT2    
GROUP BY [Key], [Employee Name], [Age]
```

Output:

```
Key Employee Name    Age    First Floor     Basement    Parking Lot A
1            Tim     40           1000          3000    
2           John      5           2000          4000             5000
```